# Use ternary operator to change className in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm making a quiz app in React/Typescript using Bootstrap. I want to make it so that the buttons use the bg-light style before the user clicks on it.

When the user selects an answer, the button should switch to bg-success if its the correct answer or bg-danger if its the wrong one.

So far what I've got is the following:

```js
className={`answers btn btn-light && ${
    correct === ans ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger'
}`}
```

Whenever I try this, the buttons stay as btn-light. I tried switching btn-light with btn-secondary, but all the answers immediately used either btn-success or btn-danger based on whether or not they were the right answer, even before being selected.

How do I get them to switch to the right className based on whether or not they're the correct answer and only after the user has clicked on an answer?

Comment: "Whenever I try this, the buttons stay as btn-light" — You are unconditionally including `btn-light` in the list of classes, so why would you expect anything else?

Comment: Write your logic outside of the template. Its much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me more like a string template than a ternary operator.

I would instead calculate the class in a variable rather than put it directly into the CSS

```
const correct === ans ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger';
className={`answers btn btn-light ${correct}`}
```

but I think you can do this:

```
 className={`answers btn btn-light ${ correct === ans ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger'}`}
```

Comment: "I would instead calculate the class in a variable rather than put it directly into the CSS" — While that is a neater bit of code, you've just refactored it to do exactly the same thing with different syntax. You're moving the deck chairs around on the titanic.

Comment: "but I think you can do this:" — That now picks one of two options based on the truthiness of a variable instead of it matching the value of a different variable. I'm pretty sure you've just created a new problem without solving the existing one.

Comment: you are right, slight typo error, thanks for the correction on point number two

Comment: Well, if that was a typo … your code now does the same thing as the original code in the question, so you still haven't fixed anything.

Comment: it's a matter of a formating a  string template more than the usage of the && operator which is not necessary

Comment: Are you suggesting that removing new lines from the string passed to `className` will solve the problem? (If so, you're wrong, it won't).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it won't ever switch from btn-light is that there's nothing that turns it off. One solution would be having a separate variable that sees if you're hovering on the button, and a ternary operator that looks something like this:

```js
<element-name className={`answers btn ${
    correct !== ans && hover ? 'btn-light' : ''
} ${
    correct === ans ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger'
}`}>
```

Comment: "The HTML parser stops parsing at that point because it only accepts letters and dashes in the class names" — Nonsense. https://jsbin.com/wiyozohaye/1/edit?html,css,output (The double ampersand is garbage, but removing it won't help at all).

Comment: Sorry, that was the only explanation I could think of. I'll remove that part of the answer.